# Retrieving current url with angular in a rails app

Tags: angularjs

I have a rails app that is using Angular

if i am at a url like "/items/3", how can i retrieve the id (in this case, 3) through the angularjs controller?

i have tried

```
$location.url()
```

, but i am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'url'
```

i included $location, is there anything else i need to do?

Also, are there other ways to retrieve the id through the Angular controller?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When configuring your routes with your `$routeProvider`, you can specify variable names that can then be retrieved inside your controller.

example app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/items/:item_id', {
        templateUrl: 'views/item.html',
        controller: 'ItemCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

And then you can resolve your item id in your controller by injecting the `$routeParams` angular object in your controller like so:

ItemCtrl.js:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('ItemCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    var itemId = $routeParams.item_id;
});
```